# How can I defer the loading of a PopupView control until it is used?

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction

Background: I have several `PopupView`s of which the loadtime adds to the startup time of a program. To improve the perceived performance I want to defer the loading of the `PopupView` to the moment that they are actually used. I thought about this:

```
  Clear[filelist];
  Clear[obj];
  filelist = {};
  Dynamic@PopupView[filelist, Dynamic[obj, (obj = #;) &], 
    Button["Edit", filelist = {1, 2, 3}, ImageSize -> 80]]
```

The idea works but not as expected, the popupview is not displayed correctly until filelist is loaded. I want to correct this or find an alternative way to set this up.

**Question: How can I defer the loading of a `PopupView` control until it is used ?**

Comment: A simple `If[filelist==={}, #, PopupView[filelist, ...]]&[Button...]` can fix the layout, but you would still need to click `Edit` twice before the popup appears

Comment: Clicking twice is too sloppy. Hmmm.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. You have a `PopupView` whose list elements take long to execute, and you want them to only execute when you open the `PopupView`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, define `PopupView` with empty reference list and **only** substitute real reference list `ref` into the `PopupView` if it is first clicked. This is done by wrapping the `PopupView` in an `EventHandler`. The dynamically displayed `list` next to the initially empty `PopupView` shows that before clicking, it is empty, and only gains its value when first clicked.

```
DynamicModule[{obj = {}, list = {""}, ref = Range@100, firstClick = True},
 {
  EventHandler[Dynamic@PopupView[list, Dynamic[obj, obj = #; &]],
   {"MouseDown" :> (If[firstClick, list = ref]; firstClick = False)},
   PassEventsDown -> True
   ],
  Dynamic@list
  }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've tried to solve this with the $f_{start}$ argument of `Dynamic`'s second argument list, but it does not work as it requires not just clicking on the empty `PopupView` but **also selecting one value** (even if it is `Null`) to make the assignment inside `Dynamic`'s second argument happen.

Comment: What can I say? Superb! - Thank you very much.